# My code getting only last row into JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

This code only getting last row into json;

```
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "db_user";
$mysql_db_password = "db_password";
$mysql_db_database = "db_name";


$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password,
 $mysql_db_database);

if (!$con) {
 trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$var = array();
 $sql = "SELECT id,name FROM db_table";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
$var = $obj;
}
echo '{"users":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
```

May i request help to rectify error in my code?

Comment: instead of $var use $var[].. because the parameter for json_encode should be array

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that can be alerting you to problems.

Comment: You should also use `json_encode` to encode your *entire* JSON object, not just part: `json_encode(array('users' => $var))`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with:

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $var[] = $obj;
}
$data = ['users' => $var];
echo json_encode($data);
```

this will make $var an array of objects, otherwise you are overriding $var value.

Comment: after making suggested, there is nothing in json, no records at all.

Comment: Does your query return any data? You can also try dumping $obj in the while.

Comment: here is the dump 

array(1) { ["users"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(13) "parshotam Lal" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(14) "M.Irfan Shafiq" } } } {"users":[{"id":"1","name":"parshotam Lal"},{"id":"2","name":"M.Irfan Shafiq"}]}

Comment: So json_encode on this should work. What is the output of `echo json_encode($data);`?

Comment: the table has 316 rows, to show you dump i ran sql with limit 2, it worked fine but when i removed limit again its not giving anything :(

Comment: So may be you have some data in DB that breaks json_encode. Is your data in utf8 ?

Comment: Do you have SET NAMES utf8 in your db connection ?

Comment: No .. i got it. let me do this and get back.

Comment: I`m glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

use array sign `[]` after `$var`

```
$var = array();
  while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
  $var[]  = $obj;
}
```

Comment: after making suggested change, there is nothing in json, no records at all.

Comment: please try var_dump($obj);  inside while loop and let me know if your query is returning data.Also check after while loop.